# Using DocuSign's CORRECTION functionality as a service in Salesforce via API

Tags: docusignapi, error-correction

DocuSign has a Correcting option (to correct an envelope after it has been sent and before it is signed by the recipient) when you are logged into their site - is there a way to utilize this functionality through SFDC through a web service API? Where we send the unique envelope ID and the changed data to DocuSign, and they in turn revise the doc in the background? The recipient will see the updated document when he accesses the document to sign it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do this from within an Apex class on SFDC. Don't use a trigger for the class, only a Lightening or force page, since triggered classes have too many restrictions on callouts to other services.